# How to create test class for FeedComment with mentioned user?

Tags: apex, trigger, chatter

I have a trigger that run on FeedComment, and now I need to create a trigger for FeedComment that contain mentioned User.

I have create an Test class like this

```
   @isTest
   public class FeedItemTriggerTest{
    @IsTest(SeeAllData=true)
    private static void createFeedTest(){
        Account a = new Account(Name = 'Test Account');
        insert a;
        
        FeedItem fItem = new FeedItem();
        fItem.Parentid = a.Id;
        fItem.Type = 'ContentPost';
        fItem.Body = 'Hello';
        insert fItem;
        
        Test.startTest();
        FeedComment fComm = new FeedComment();
        fComm.CommentBody = '@Testing Chatter Check';
        fComm.FeedItemId = fItem.Id;
        insert fComm;    
        Test.stopTest();
    }
}
```

But this test class cannot get the mentioned users in the CommentBody. Please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can do that now. Following to this article.
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/connectapi_examples_post_comment_feed_element_3.htm

```
String feedElementId = '0D5D0000000KtW3';

ConnectApi.CommentInput commentInput = new ConnectApi.CommentInput();

ConnectApi.MessageBodyInput messageBodyInput = new ConnectApi.MessageBodyInput();
ConnectApi.TextSegmentInput textSegmentInput = new ConnectApi.TextSegmentInput();

textSegmentInput.text = 'Enjoy this new file.';

messageBodyInput.messageSegments = new List<ConnectApi.MessageSegmentInput>();
messageBodyInput.messageSegments.add(textSegmentInput);
commentInput.body = messageBodyInput;

ConnectApi.CommentCapabilitiesInput commentCapabilitiesInput = new ConnectApi.CommentCapabilitiesInput();
ConnectApi.ContentCapabilityInput contentCapabilityInput = new ConnectApi.ContentCapabilityInput();

commentCapabilitiesInput.content = contentCapabilityInput;
contentCapabilityInput.title = 'Title';

commentInput.capabilities = commentCapabilitiesInput;

String text = 'These are the contents of the new file.';
Blob myBlob = Blob.valueOf(text);
ConnectApi.BinaryInput binInput = new ConnectApi.BinaryInput(myBlob, 'text/plain', 'fileName');

ConnectApi.Comment commentRep = ConnectApi.ChatterFeeds.postCommentToFeedElement(Network.getNetworkId(), feedElementId, commentInput, binInput);
```

Comment: Welcome to SFSE! Please check out [answer] and then [edit] your post

Comment: Thanks for your reminder I have updated to the answer